# Flash video in movieclip problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have several video files playing on the stage. I've converted them into movieclips so that I can scale and drag them by clicking. The problem is that I cannot loop them.

Then I tried to make them as SWF playback object's but after that my code wasn't working with them.

Next step was to make them Embedded video objects so that they loop automatically and the code is working. After that there appeared a problem that the objects are duplicating at some point.

Here's the original code as the videos are movieclips.

```
    var allDraggables:Array = new Array();
var mouseHold = false;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);

function mUp(MouseEvent)
{
 mouseHold = false;
}

function draggableObject(mc)
{
 var mouseOnThisObject = false;
 allDraggables.push(mc);
 mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, drag);
 mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
 function mDown(MouseEvent)
 {
  mouseHold = true;
  mouseOnThisObject = true;
 }

 function drag(MouseEvent)
 {

  if (mouseHold == true && mouseOnThisObject == true)
  {
   mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragger);
  }

  if (mouseHold == false)
  {
   mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragger);
   mouseOnThisObject = false;
  }


 }

 mc.doubleClickEnabled = true;
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, scaleMe);

function scaleMe(e:MouseEvent)
{


if (e.target.scaleX < 2)
{
e.target.scaleX= e.target.scaleY = 2;
}
else (e.target.scaleX= e.target.scaleY = 1);
}




 function dragger(Event)
 {
  mc.x+=(mouseX-mc.x)/3;
  mc.y+=(mouseY-mc.y)/3;

  for (var i:int=0; i<allDraggables.length; i++){
  if(mc.hitTestObject(allDraggables[i]) && getChildIndex(allDraggables[i]) > getChildIndex(mc)){
   swapChildren(allDraggables[i], mc)
   }
  }
 }
}





draggableObject(green);
draggableObject(red);
draggableObject(video1);
draggableObject(video2);
draggableObject(video3);
```

Comment: So what I want as result, is that the videos are acting like movieclips, and they are looping. Doesn't matter which way I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's hard to tell what you've tried exactly, since you haven't provided any code (yet)..

However, from the top of my head, I think this will work:

```
if(videoMC1.currentFrame == 250) { //put the number of the last frame of the movieclip in place of 250
   loopMC();
}
function loopMC() {
   videoMC1.stop();
   videoMC1.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

What you do here is simple; you check the current frame that is passed/playing and when it reaches the desired number (in your case most likely the last frame) it calls a function that resets and plays the video.

Answer (score 0):

I found some old code I once used in a project, maybe you could try this. In my flash app it worked, although I didn't put the video into a movieclip.

```
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

nc.connect(null);
ns = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.bufferTime = 10;

var vid:Video = new Video(1024,640);
vid.attachNetStream(ns);
addChild(vid);
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ns_onPlayStatus)

function ns_onPlayStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {//loop video
    if(event.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
        ns.seek(0);
    }
}
```